# Pass command-line arguments to script's 'internal' function

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a simple PowerShell script:

```powershell
# Foobar.ps1
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [alias("i")]
    [String[]]
    $IDs,

    [parameter()]
    [alias("b")]
    [string]
    $Bar
)

Foreach ($ID in $IDs) {
    write-host $ID
}

write-host $Bar

PS> .\foobar -i 1234,5678 -b 'hello world'
1234
5678
hello world
```

I want refactor the script to make use of the advanced features of `CmdletBinding`:

```powershell
# Foobar.ps1
Function Invoke-Foo {

  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
      [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [alias("i")]
      [String[]]
      $IDs,

      [parameter()]
      [alias("u")]
      [string]
      $Bar
  )

  Begin {}
  Process {
    Foreach ($ID in $IDs) {
        write-host $ID
    }
    write-host $Bar
  }
  End {}

}

# call internal function with command-line's arguments; only pass -b if it exists
Invoke-Foo -i <command line arg -i> -b <command line arg -b>

PS> .\foobar -i 1234,5678 -b 'hello world'
1234
5678
hello world

PS> .\foobar -i 111,222
111
222
```

How to do I correctly capture and pass the command-line argument to the internal function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most-efficient solution, but it seems to work:

```
Foobar.ps1

# capture named arguments from command line
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [alias("i")]
    [String[]]
    $IDs,
    [parameter()]
    [alias("b")]
    [string]
    $Bar
)

# internal function
Function Invoke-Foo {

  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [alias("i")]
    [String[]]
    $IDs,
    [parameter()]
    [alias("b")]
    [string]
    $Bar
  )

  Begin {Write-Host 'Begin'}
  Process {
    Write-Host 'Process'
    Foreach ($ID in $IDs) {
        write-host $ID
    }
    If ($Bar) {write-host $Bar}
  }
  End {Write-Host 'End'}

}

# invoke internal function, supplying named arguments
Invoke-Foo -i $IDs -b $Bar
```

Comment: My suggestion would have been to do something along these lines. FYI alias is redundant in this scenario as `i` and `b` are already non-ambiguous. You should be able to remove the lines like `[alias("i")]` and nothing would change. Alias would be for synonyms more than brevity like `[alias("Numbers")]`

Comment: You mean specifying the aliases in the Function's param section, right?

Comment: Correct and to be more specific the aliases you chose specifically. PowerShell is lenient when using short names as long as they are not ambiguous. `Get-ChildItem -pa c:\temp` where `pa` could only be `-Path`. `-p` could be `-PipelineVariable` or `-Path` so you would get an error

Comment: Also, if someone else had to read the code it would be a good practice not to use the same variable names inside different scopes. You script as is would obviously work but with more complicate ones you could run a risk.